# Vim split arguments, undo "J"

Tags: vim, regex

I find it much easier to arguments of a function, elements of a list etc when they are split on different lines. If this is harder to read I can join them later by "J". How should one go about splitting everything within parenthesis. It seems to be some kind of regex search'n'replace pattern but I could not find a way to make it work regardless of arguments and indentation level:

Examples:

```
Example 1:
parser.add_argument('--viz', action='store_true', help='to show vizualisation or not')

Desired output:
parser.add_argument('--viz',
        action='store_true',
        help='to show vizualisation or not')


Example 2:
Input:
parser.add_argument('--viz', action='store_true', lambda: print("sometext here"))

Desired output:
parser.add_argument('--viz',
        action='store_true',
        lambda: print("sometext here"))


Example 3:
Input:
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    temp = ['asd', 123, true]

Desired output:
def func(*args,
         **kwargs):

    temp = ['asd',
             123,
             true]
```

[image: Example of what I want]

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/624838/372239

Comment: Answers there are highly unsatisfactory and naive implementation something like ":s/ /\r/g" extension does not solve 2nd and 3rd example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is python code, as it seems to me, my [splitjoin](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/splitjoin.vim) plugin seems to do the correct thing for all of these examples, with some indentation differences (which come from the built-in indentation script anyway).

This isn't so much an answer in terms of "this is how you do it", because it's a complicated problem, when you need to count brackets, ignore strings and so on. It's why I wrote an entire plugin for this stuff, which handles each situation with a different callback function. I can only suggest you try it out and see if it fits well with your use cases.

Comment: Installed it, modified it, using it.